# Harmonic Polynomial Function

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions

I can't figure out this question:

For what values of the constants A and B is the polynomial function
$F(x,y) = (-5)x^5 + Ax^{3}y^{2} + Bxy^{4}$
harmonic in the whole $xy$-plane?

$A=?$
$B=?$

Comment: So, where did the computations of the Laplacian led you?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a harmonic function? Do you know how to calculate partial derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

(Just to save this question from going unanswered for ever)

For $F$ to be harmonic we need 
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} = 0$$
throughout the plane.

Since $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} = -100x^3 + 6Axy^2$ and $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} = 2Ax^3 + 12Bxy^2$, this means that we need the function $-100x^3 + 6Axy^2 + 2Ax^3 + 12Bxy^2$ to be identically zero throughout the plane.

This implies that $2A-100=0$ and $12B+6B=0$, giving $a=50$ and $B=-25$, and thus the harmonic function is $F(x,y) = -5x^5 + 50x^3y^2 - 25xy^4.$